# Makeing my site available through static IP

Tags: static-ip-address

So I just finished development of a prototype of my MVC site.

It uses a local instance of a full SQL Server 2008 install, and I'm developing just with the development serves that come with Visual Studio 2010.

Is there ANYWAY I can make this available to my friend to log on and test some stuff out? Or is there no way unless I'm using IIS or something.

Also, I'd want him to be able to like, use it fully, so access to the DB, etc.

Thanks ahead of time guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Fiddler on your local dev machine. And setting up your remote machine to use fiddler as its proxy.

[Remote machines cannot connect to Visual Studio web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220274/remote-machines-cannot-connect-to-visual-studio-web-server)

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/reverseproxy.asp

OR

If it's just access he requires. He could remote to your machine :s

Start>Run  mstsc