# Can't access Visual Studio project from IP, only http://localhost

Tags: visual-studio, virtual-machine

I'm running a project in visual studio.  I hit run and it launches IE pointing at `http://localhost:1267`

If I try to visit `http://10.211.55.3:1267` (the machine's IP), I get nothing, even when visiting from the same machine.  IIS7 works fine.

The machine is actually a VM running in parallels.

Any ideas what's may be going on?

Comment: Does the application run correctly when visiting the localhost address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the Visual Studio Development Server (and not IIS,) your server will only bind to localhost.  You can not use another IP address to access it.  If you must, you can [work around this with proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220274/remote-machines-cannot-connect-to-visual-studio-web-server).

If you are running IIS, make sure that your web server is binding to all addresses (0.0.0.0)

Comment: Thanks.  Is it possible to make VS push a project to IIS?

Comment: Please note that it should also be possible to resolve your application using `http://127.0.0.1:1267` as well.

Comment: @Bryan - yeah, but that doesn't exactly help me :)

Comment: Yes, just point IIS to your project directory as an application.  Then click on project properties, web tab, and set server to "Use Local IIS Web server"

Comment: You are wrong, it can be done via bindingInformation

Answer (score 3):

**CygWin Solution** (no proxy install needed)

```
ssh USER@OTHER_HOST -R IIS_PORT:localhost:IIS_PORT
```

replace `USER`, `OTHER_HOST` and `IIS_PORT`. Now you can browse with your `OTHER_HOST` to the testpage on `localhost:IIS_PORT`. This enables you the ability to test your stuff on remote Linux hosts (for example).

Comment: Of course a proper, clean and easy solution to this problem is downvoted once useful non-microsoft stuff is invloved. Does not surprise me at all.

Answer (score 1):

For **IIS Express**, you need to grant yourself permission to bind to network adapters other than localhost, and configure IIS express to bind to all adapters. If you desire access from another computer, you need to also open the port on your firewall. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18958879/145173) details these steps.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to edit applicationhost.config file manually

```
<bindings>
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:57177:localhost" />
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:57177:127.0.0.1" />
</bindings>
```

Aplication will be accessible on:

```
localhost:57177
127.0.0.1:57177
```

If you want remote access, I think adding your IP address and disabling firewall will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing the IIS server to Local
Right Click Web Project - Properties - Web - Select Local IIS