# Connecting to IIS Express using Android emulator

Tags: android, iis, networking

I am using the loopback 10.0.2.2 and connecting to the port its running on but it always returns "HTTP Error 400 - The request hostname is invalid"

So does anyone know how to connect to IIS express in the Android emulator?

Comment: I have this issue with ApiController, I made it work using Controller instead and return JsonResult

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Android Emulator loopback to IIS Express does not work, but does work with Cassini](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6192726/145173)

Comment: You can follow https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-let-android-emulator-access-iis-express-f6530a02b1d3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS Express access from Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622782/iis-express-access-from-android-emulator)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this using IIS Express. For now, to get around this problem, I switched over to use the Visual Studio Development Server (Cassini).

You will also need to check the versions of jquery and jquery mobile, to verify that they are compatible. I was running with jquery-ui-1.8.11, which I downloaded, but used jquery-1.5.1 which came with the ASP.NET MVC 3 app template.
When I replaced the jquery 1.5.1 with jquery 1.7.2, it started working.

According to:
http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/04/13/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0/
jquery mobile 1.1.0 final requires jQuery core 1.6.4 or 1.7.1

Comment: I am running into the same issue. I am looking for a solution too

Comment: Double check the versions of the javascript tools you are using - the jquery libraries need to match. jquery is picky about this sort of thing.

Comment: Thank you!!! Switching over to development server in VS fixed the issue. I have been messing around with this problem for hours.

Comment: The Visual Studio Development Server also worked for me. Thanks for the solution.