# IIS Express access from Android emulator

Tags: android, iis-express, visual-studio-2017

I know similar questions have been asked many times, but I still can't get it working correctly. I'd like to be able to access IIS Express on my host machine from my Visual Studio Android emulator. I have the following bindings in my .vs\config\applicationHost.config file for my website:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:7265:MyComp" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44300:MyComp" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:7265:10.0.2.2" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44300:10.0.2.2" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:7265:localhost" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44300:localhost" />
```

When I run the website on my host, in the list of running applications, I see the bindings for MyComp and localhost listed, but not the ones for 10.0.2.2. On my host I can connect using MyComp or localhost without issue.

In the emulator, I can use http://10.0.2.2 to connect to IIS 7.5 (not express) on my host computer with no issue. In my emulator what I can't do is connect to http://10.0.2.2:7265 or https://10.0.2.2:44300 which is a site being run in IIS Express. I get an HTTP 400 error "The request hostname is invalid.". I'm sure this is because I don't have the IIS bindings set up correctly, but nothing I try works. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try your computer name instead of the IP.

Comment: I did try it, but I get a host name not found DNS error. I'm new to Android dev, but was under the impression you had to use 1 of a couple specific IPs for connections to the host....

Answer (score 22):

You missed a few basic facts. 10.0.2.2 on Android emulator is translated to 127.0.0.1 on the host. Thus, change your bindings to

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:7265:127.0.0.1" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44300:127.0.0.1" />
```

You can also remove host headers from bindings by following [this blog post](https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/how-to-let-android-emulator-access-iis-express-f6530a02b1d3).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I ended up switching to regular IIS on the project instead of IIS Express so I can't test your answer, but it makes sense...

Comment: Thanks this answer specifically helped with connecting via HTTPS on the emulator.  Android emulator set to Android Studio HTTP proxy settings and connected via https:10.0.2.2:443##/

Answer (score 3):

In your .NET project Go to project settings | Debug and replace "localhost" to your loopback adapter "127.0.0.1" in your "app url" string.

Worked for me.
[app url setting in .NET project/debug settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj4bP.png)