# How to run localhost webapi on xamarin forms

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I have a xamarin forms app and a web api.

when I run the web api, on the browser I have http://localhost:53089/api/values

and inside the xamarin app I have the following method

```
public async Task<object> GetRestfull()
    {

        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var content = await client.GetStringAsync("http://10.0.2.2:53089/api/values");
                var postt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Post>>(content);
                post = new ObservableCollection<Post>(postt);
            }             

            return post.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.GetBaseException().Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I'm using the android avd emulator.

and the above code throws an exception : 400 bad request
if I remove the port number it throws : 404 not found.

I have checked my firewall settings and world wide web is enabled.. so what is it that I'm missing here? any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-let-android-emulator-access-iis-express-f6530a02b1d3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS Express access from Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622782/iis-express-access-from-android-emulator)

Comment: how do I add my restful services as website to jexus manager?

Comment: https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/getting-started/features.html#add-new-servers

Answer (score 0):

try replace localhost with 127.0.0.1

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.