# Invalid HostName - Not able to connect IIS express from Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, asp.net-mvc, android-emulator

I am trying to connect a WCF service hosted at my local IIS express from an Android app. Currently, I am testing this on an Emulator.

Local URL for the service is  `http://locahost:40000/api/Authenticate`

I knew that localhost is not going to work and I used 10.0.2.2 in the code

```
post = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:40000/api/authenticate");
```

but the response on client execute is an "Invalid Hostname"

I tried editing the  ApplicationHost.config of IIS express and added a binding entry for 10.0.2.2 but that didn't work too

Is there anything else that I am missing ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Emulator loopback to IIS Express does not work, but does work with Cassini](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192726/android-emulator-loopback-to-iis-express-does-not-work-but-does-work-with-cassi)

Comment: You can try the config changes in the answers or use our free extension, which imho is easier https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried something else which worked , I added the IP address of my system within the IIS Express applicationhost.config file bindings sections.

```
<bindings>
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:40000:localhost" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:40000:192.168.5.118" />
</bindings>
```

I am able to call the service now

Comment: article **replaces** the bindingInformation, don't do that, do as @Kunal does and make a copy.

Answer (score 12):

As I understand it, 10.0.2.2 is an alias for 127.0.0.1, so add that to your `applicationhost.config` binding for your site, e.g.

```
 <site name="MySite" id="1">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="{yourpath}" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:26013:localhost" />
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:26013:127.0.0.1" />
    </bindings>
  </site>
```

Bear in mind that these days if you're using Visual Studio the relevant `applicationhost.config` for your site may not be in `c:\users\...` but rather in a `.vs\config` folder at the root of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In a **.NetCore** project on **visual studio 2022**,

I edited the **launchSettings.json** file, under iisSettings > applicationUrl i set the url to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` , somthing like this.

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:59109",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  }
```

and in the flutter app the url is `10.0.2.2:59109`

Answer (score -2):

Add `Internet Permission`, `Network State`, and `Wifi` **Permission in AndroidManifest.xml**

Answer (score -3):

1. What's with "port 40000"???????
   I'd *definitely* try a lower port number (like something below 32768 ;))
2. Make sure your androidmanifest.xml has internet permissions
3. Make sure "api/authenticate" is defined and available in IIS
4. Make sure Windows firewall isn't blocking port 40000
5. Useful tools include:

   - ping (so you can "ping 10.0.0.2"; available in OOTB Windows)
   - telnet (so you can "telnet localhost NNN"; you must add this in Windows Features)
   - Firefox and Firebug
   - Wireshark

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with the port the number. 40000 works when I call the API from the fiddler. All this is working on fiddler but not on Android.

Comment: Also, I have these permissions listed in manifest file:

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: @Paulsm4, well there is no need for this..but still i want to mention that every TCP/IP connection has 65536 ports counting from 0, else its 65535.. so 40000 is quite a valid one.... thanks...