# Get JSON for android on C # + WebApi

Tags: android, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebService in C # which uses webapi and provides a json  through the one url , until there ok.

```
public class UsuarioByGroupController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/getusuariobygroup
    public List<DTOUsuario> Get()
    {
        int valor = 0;
        return new RepUsuario().GetUsuarioByGrupo(6, 0, int.MaxValue, null, null, out valor).ToList();
    }
```

In android I have a method that a "get" the WebService passing the url (this method works in another app):

```
private static final String URI = "http://10.0.2.2:3671/api/";


public static <T> T get(String url, T e) throws Exception {

    String[] json = new WebService().get(URI + url);

    List<T> obj = new ArrayList<T>();

    if (json[0].equals("200")) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonArray array = parser.parse(json[1]).getAsJsonArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            obj.add(gson.fromJson(array.get(i), (Class<T>) e));
        }
        return (T) obj;
    } else {
        throw new Exception(json[1]);
    }
}
```

But it returns me the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

**EDIT:**

```
public final String[] get(String url) {

    String[] result = new String[2];
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response;

    try {
        response = HttpClientSingleton.getHttpClientInstace().execute(
            httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            result[0] = String.valueOf(response.getStatusLine()
                .getStatusCode());
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            result[1] = toString(instream);
            instream.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("NGVL", "Falha ao acessar Web service", e);
        result[0] = "0";
        result[1] = "Falha na rede!";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It looks like whatever `WebService.get()` is doing with the provided URI/URL is incorrect. Please post that method.

Comment: ok, ready, added the method.Thanks

Comment: Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/11800718/1253844. It may be an IIS configuration issue.

Comment: I like using [Postman](http://getpostman.com/) to try out my calls to WebApi beforehand. You can build all kinds of requests there, and test that things are actually working as expected, therefore isolating any problems in the Api, its configuration or the parameters you're sending.

Comment: @Tanis.7x, thanks for that, i managed to solve this problem by publishing my project on IIS server C# as in java not have and eclipse already does this.

So, just published my C# project in IIS that worked, thanks again.    **EDIT:** Please add an answer and mark it ok.