# flex 4.6 : using URLLoader in flex mobile Application

Tags: asp.net, web-services, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

I'm beginner in Flex mobile application , my issue when using flex mobile application that interact with services with asp.net 
i try to load URLString in flex mobile application ,but it always go to NoConnection function 
when i use break point and the mobile is connected to the internet
this is my code

```
                protected function Submit():void
        {

            SendLoader = new URLLoader();
            var URLString:String ="http://localhost:1614/Master_Services/Problems/insertProblem.aspx";
            SendLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,NoConnection);
            SendLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS,httperror);
            SendLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,SendComplete);
            SendLoader.load(new URLRequest(URLString));

        }
```

update : this URL worked well in the computer browser , but in mobile browser it couldn't load and give me web Page not available . I think this may the problem , if this the problem , Any idea to load url placed in localhost in moblie while Im debuging via USB .

Please help , Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `localhost` to your computer's IP address.  In the mobile browser, your code is trying to connect to port 1614 on the device instead of port 1614 on your development computer.

Also make sure that your firewall is configured to allow requests to come in to that port; it's an easy step to miss.  You might need to deploy your code to IIS on your computer to make this work, too.  The built-in webserver for Visual Studio will only work from localhost (see [Can't access Visual Studio project from IP, only http://localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901224/cant-access-visual-studio-project-from-ip-only-http-localhost)).