# Cross domain request to ASP.NET Web API

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have a question regarding the implementation of cors in a ASP.NET Web API.
The reason I am turning to SO is that I've tried searching everywhere, and found a lot of tutorials and answers, but none of those seem to work for me.

---

### Setup:

- Web Application (HTML5, JS) running on XAMPP **(192.168.1.101:8080)**
- API (ASP.net) running on IIS Express (Integrated with VS2013) **(192.168.1.101:52126)**

The web application makes ajax calls to the API as shown in the code block below.

```
$.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    type:  'POST',
    url:   'http://localhost:52126/api/controller/action',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
    headers:
    {
        "Authorization": "Basic Base64Encrpytion"
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
        // Handle success
    },
    error: function(data)
    {
        // Handle error
    }
});
```

This all works perfectly in **localhost** including OPTION preflight. But when I start the web application from a other device in the same local network, the preflight fails and ofcourse if the preflight fails the rest of the calls get canceled as well.

---

### Error:

When trying to query the API from another device **(192.168.1.100)** in the same network using the web application the following responses are generated:

**Console**

```
OPTIONS http://192.168.1.101:52126/api/controller/action 400 (Bad Request)
OPTIONS http://192.168.1.101:52126/api/controller/action No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.101:8080/' is therefore not allowed access.
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.101:52126/api/controller/action. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.101:8080/' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**Response Header**

```
Connection: close
Content-Length: 334
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Date: Wed, 05 Mar 2014 09:29:46 GMT
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

The response header **does** contain the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"** header when testing the web application and API on localhost.

---

### Solutions I have tried:

Adding the code below to each class that needs to be reached from outside the domain.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Adding the code below to the Web.config file.

```
<httpprotocol>
  <customheaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"></add>
  </customheaders>
</httpprotocol>
```

Adding the code below to the WebApiConfig file.

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Adding the code below to the applicationhost.config

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="192.168.1.101:52126:*" />
```

The following setting is set to true

```
jQuery.support.cors = true
```

I have also tried to override the preflight handler, but that seemed to fail as well.

Comment: remember that Chrome does not allow you to run that example as you have `localhost` on the url. use Firefox for example or change the binding to your machine name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have changed localhost to the ip of the machine itself, when i do that the errors popup. When using localhost everything seems to work fine. Also i am trying to reach the API from a different device in the network.

Comment: to expose the API in your network without deploying into IIS, please [read my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6008350/28004) to an old question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wasting two days on this problem, i think i've solved it.

Since i am developing on a workstation in a corporate network i don't have local administrator rights. Which means i have to run Visual Studio 2013 in Administrator Mode. [That way IIS Express can run on the network instead of only localhost.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4869367/739972)

In the applicationhost.config i did the following:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50157:localhost" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50157:192.168.1.101" />
```

Which obviously fails because they are both assigned to the same port. So i changed that to:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50157:localhost" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50158:192.168.1.101" />
```

**TL;DR**

- Make sure you run Visual Studio in adminstrator mode or just obtain local administrator rights.
- Use a different port for each ip.

Comment: Thanks, All I needed to do was run my Visual Studio in Administration mode! Again thanks, suffered for almost 4 hours until I found your post!

Signalr doing Cors will give XMLHttpRequest cannot load No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource.

Even if you did everything correctly - Smiling now :)