# Accessing Visual Studio 2010 debugging website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, mobile

I am going to develop a ASP.net website for mobiles. But I found that my mobile cannot access the website during debugging the website.

How to let the VS 2010 can be accessed form my mobile during debugging website?

Comment: From localhost? Don't think that'll happen.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the question? Are having trouble connecting to the web site from your mobile? Or is it only while debugging?

Comment: I believe he's asking about connecting to the debugging asp.net web server provided with VS2010 for web projects. Which should be as easy as getting on the network and connecting to (IP):(Whatever port the web server tells you it's running on). Too lazy to try though.

Comment: I mean I run a asp.net website as debug or release in VS 2010. In the localhost(running VS 2010), each browser can browse the website. But the other computers or mobiles cannot browse the website, even I disable the firewall. To test the connecting, I run an Apache server, the other computers can connect the server.

Comment: it rings a bell that the developper/debugging website may not allow connections from somewhere else on purpose (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220274/remote-machines-cannot-connect-to-visual-studio-web-server). You might want to debug in IIS and then attach the VS Debugger to IIS process.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to access it and debug it from your mobile device you have to deploy it to your local IIS on the default website. If you connect your mobile device on the same wifi/local network you should be able to browse the site from your mobile using the computers hostname.