# Deployment of ASP.net site for remote access

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, deployment

As per my understanding Visual Studio has a default Deployment Server for ASP.net sites, what should be done if i need to access this site on intranet.

I created a web site in Visual Studio 2010 using asp.net and vb this works fine on localhost but if another friend of mine tries to access it from his pc (he is in the same netwrk) he gets access denied error.

Queries -

1. should there be a external server whr i should host this site
2. which is bttr IIS or apache or mono or something....
3. is there any other way pf remotely accessing this site

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Set up IIS on your computer. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBNoTK31zPo
   You can set up a virtual directory that points to your project folder.
2. Use a proxy if you don't want to or can't set up IIS. [Remote machines cannot connect to Visual Studio web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220274/remote-machines-cannot-connect-to-visual-studio-web-server)