# Consuming ASP.NET Web Api service from other computer in LAN

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I googled about this, but could't find anything which will fix my problem.
(I'm new to ASP.NET Web Api)

I built an ASP.NET Web Api and when I run it from visual studio on the local machine everthing is working perfect. (in both cases it work fine, when I use "Use Visual Studio Development Server" and also "Use Local IIS Web server").

The problem is when I tried to call this web service from other computer in the lan network it didn't worked (somthing like: "http://192.168.2.103:8080/api/blabla").
(1) with "Use Visual Studio Development Server" - the client finish with timeout.
(2) with "Use Local IIS Web server" - the client received HTTP ERROR 400 "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname" (this when I'm using port 8080 and added rule to windows firewall to pass this port).

I also tried to fully disable windows-firewall, anti-virus and it didn't help.

I have other http web service project implemented in WCF and there everything is OK, I can communicate it from other computer in lan.

NOTE! 
(1) the other computer is not windows....if it is important)
(2) ping between the to computers/adresses is working OK.

I will realy appreciate any help.
thanks,

Haim

Comment: What happens when you use http://192.168.2.103:8080/api/blabla rather than localhost on the local computer?

Comment: If I'm using 192.168.2.103:8080/api/blabla I get the same problem, HTTP ERROR 400 "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname".

Comment: @Haim  am facing the same problem.... did u find any solution for this?

Comment: https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/02/27/remote-access-to-local-aspnet-core-apps-from-mobile-devices/

Answer (score 1):

(1) visual studio development server does not support remote connections. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220274/remote-machines-cannot-connect-to-visual-studio-web-server) for more details. People try workarounds like setting a reverse proxy in these scenarios.

(2) By "Local IIS web server", I assume you are using IIS Express. Unfortunately, IIS Express doesn't allow remote connections by default. To allow remote connections, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433786/configure-iis-express-for-external-access-to-vs2010-project).