# How to make a ASP.NET Core API Internally accessible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am writing an ASP.NET Core API that I want to access on my internal network, how can I make it internally accessible?

I tried following the steps on this thread: [Remotely connect to .net core self hosted web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732279/remotely-connect-to-net-core-self-hosted-web-api)

But I am still not able to access it.

This is the code for my Program.cs:

```
    public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            var ip = GetLocalIPAddress();

            var url = $"http://{ip}:5000";
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                        .UseKestrel()
                        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .UseUrls("http://localhost:5000", url)
                        .UseIISIntegration()
                        .UseStartup<Startup>()
                        .Build();
            host.Run();
        }
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();

    public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
    }
}
```

Simple endpoint that I am trying to reach:

```
[Route("api/heartbeat")]
[ApiController]
public class HeartbeatController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpHead]
    public IActionResult Head()
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {

        var ip = GetLocalIPAddress();
        return Ok($"Success ~ Api started on :  http://{ip}:5000");
    }

    private static string GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just listen on `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: Did you check if your `GetLocalIPAddress` returns the correct IP?

Comment: @MindSwipe yes I did

Comment: @spender to listen to it on 0.0.0.0, do I just add "http://0.0.0.0:5000" on the UseUrls list?

Comment: Then try removing `UseIISIntegration`, as your process is self hosted and not reliant on any other web server/ reverse Proxy

Comment: @MindSwipe I still get a connection refused error

Comment: What happens when you try binding to port 80 (default HTTP port)?

Comment: Can you pls check it with localhost IP i.e. ``http://127.0.0.1:5000``

Comment: @Mindswipe I did try binding to port 80, didn't make a difference

Comment: @MukeshVadodariya I tried using your example port, I still get a connection refused error

Comment: Did you check the machine firewall? it's allowed to communicate required ports?

Comment: @EmilevRooyen Indeed, that's exactly what I mean. It means "all IPv4 addresses on the local machine" IIRC.