# Connect device on LAN to ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, lan

I'm running VS2019 community, and I've created the default ASP.NET Core Web API project (ASP.NET Core 5.0), the one with the simple weather forecast example. And I am now trying to connect another computer to the URL. I run the example by using the [application name] in the run dropdown, and not IIS Express.

Both computers are connected via wifi to the same Router.
I do an ipconfig on the server machine to get it's IP (192.168.1.108)
And I have also enabled inbound connections from the ports 5000-5001 in the windows firewall setup

On the "client" machine I try to access the server with :

http://192.168.1.108:5000/swagger/index.html

or

https://192.168.1.108:5001/swagger/index.html

but neither seem to work? The page ends up timing out.

So on the machine running the server, I also completely disabled the windows firewalls (temporally, just to get things working).

But still get the same result?

Have I missed a step?

Comment: did you open the firewall on the server pc?

Comment: In my question I state that I allow inbound connections to ports 5000-5001 and have even tried disabling the firewall all togeather

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39733403/8978576) will help you. Try to add IP of your host into Program.cs 
`var host = new WebHostBuilder().UseUrls("http://192.168.1.108:5000")`

Comment: This works, thanks. But interestingly, it still works even after turning the firewall back on and removing the inbound port rules? shouldn't I HAVE to have inbound ports 5000-5001 open for this to work?

Comment: Maybe it's a program exception(is where a firewall rule is set up to ignore inbound and outbound traffic from a specific program) but I can't certainly say