# Unable to access ASP.NET API from other computers on local network

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, webserver, http-status-code-400

I have an API written in ASP.NET and when I run it with IIS express, it opens up to the following page `https://localhost:44381/api/strs`. This works completely fine. However, when I try to access it from another computer or even my local computer using my LAN address, `https://10.0.0.185:44381/api/strs`, I get the error message `HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.`

EDIT - I realized I forgot to add that accessing from `http://10.0.0.185:19093/` also gives the same error

These are my bindings

```xml
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44381:10.0.0.185" />
                </bindings>
```

and here is my launchsettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:19093",
      "sslPort": 44381
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/strs",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "TestApi2": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/strs",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

I have been trying to solve this problem for hours but no matter what I do I just get status code 400 or "network connection reset". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this answear could help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39733403/11137121

Comment: unfortunately not, I still get the same error 400. I think I might just have to give up this project for now because I've been trying to fix this for 6 or 7 hours and I haven't made any progress

Comment: I would suggest using our free extension, Conveyor which solves this problem https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti without requiring binding editings.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis) to configure and deploy an application with IIS on windows,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).