# accessing web service published with Visual Studio 2012 with movile

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2012, remote-access

I have a Visual Studio 2012 Web Service project, which I do right click on it and the "Publish". It says that will be published in C:\MyApp, then I click on Publish. Afterwards, I Run the project and the browser opens in localhost:6688. I can access the services locally without problem using localhost.

But when I want to access them from my movile browser (typing 192.168.1.103:6688/pathToService, which is the same way I access it locally but changing the localhost to the ip where the service is published), it says "Bad Request - Invalid HostName. HTTP Error 400. he request hostname is invalid".

Also, if I want to access to the url locally by typing 192.168.1.103:6688/pathToService (changing localhost to the local ip) appears the same error.

The ip I use is the same that appears on ipconfing ipv4 address.
My firewalls are down.
The Visual Studio 2012 is running as administrator.

What am I doing wrong?
The most important thing is to access the web services from my movile

Comment: It's likely that it's only bound to `127.0.0.1` / `localhost`. Investigate to see if you can alter that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remote machines cannot connect to Visual Studio web server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220274/remote-machines-cannot-connect-to-visual-studio-web-server)

Comment: i have solved my problem. I will publish the answer soon :) thanks anyway